# MS Access Export Subform VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I've been through a bunch of posts on how to do this but I can't seem to find an answer that works.

I have the main form "SubCanButton" and the Subform "MasterQuery"

[image]

When you click submit it should export to an Excel spreadsheet with the info from the subquery "MasterQuery" but it keeps coming up blank and I can't figure it out.

My current code:

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, [Forms]![SubCanButton].Form.[MasterQuery].Name, "C:\Users\" & Owner & "\Desktop\ " & Format(Now(), "MM-DD-YY") & " Retail Change Request.xlsx", False
```

But I've also tried the following variations as well

```
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "MasterQuery", acFormatXLS, "C:\Users\" & Owner & "\Desktop\ " & Format(Now(), "MM-DD-YY") & " Retail Change Request.xlsx", False

DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputForm, [Forms]![SubCanButton].Form.[MasterQuery].Name, acFormatXLS, "C:\Users\" & Owner & "\Desktop\ " & Format(Now(), "MM-DD-YY") & " Retail Change Request.xlsx", False
```

I've also tried variations of the above as well but can't seem to get my data in the form. I'm not sure what I'm missing here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Better to export query or report, not form. And I don't think a subform can be referenced for export because it is not even opened as an independent form in Forms collection. Do you have a query object named "MasterQuery"? If yes, that code should then work. When you say "subquery", did you mean "subreport"?

Comment: @June7 yes I do have a query named "MasterQuery".  (not using reports). The MasterQuery Subquery grabs data from 2 tables and one SQL query to give me the output on the MasterQuery form.

Comment: Why do you say "Subquery", there are no 'subquery' objects. If the name of query is **MasterQuery** then code should work.

Comment: Sorry lack of a better term since it uses a query and is already a query. Right now I'm trying to see if there is a round about way of getting this to work. I've renamed the form and am trying to export MasterQuery to excel instead of the form (Having it load in the background, create the file then close) but no dice so far. Still getting no data.

Comment: Try using the correct file type: `DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "MasterQuery", acFormatXLS, "C:\Users\" & Owner & "\Desktop\ " & Format(Now(), "MM-DD-YY") & " Retail Change Request.xls", False`.

Comment: @Gustav yep this is pretty much what I did. In the background I just had the query open as well and then the file is built from that query, I then have it close after the data has been exported. Thanks Gustav and June7 I really appreciate the input and help!

Comment: Ooops, didn't think about file name extension. TransferSpreadsheet can use .xlsx extension.

Answer (score 1):

When you export data to excel then best practice is to export query so that you can pass multiple criteria to filter data to get desired results only. However if you want to export subform data or filtered subform data then you can use below sub.

```
Private Sub cmdExportSubFormToExcel_Click()
Dim rsClone As DAO.Recordset
Set rsClone = Me.subChallanStatus.Form.RecordsetClone 'subChallanStatus is subform control

If rsClone.EOF Then
MsgBox "No records found."
Set rsClone = Nothing
Exit Sub
End If

    Dim xlApp As Object
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    With xlApp
        .Visible = True
        .Workbooks.Add
        .Sheets("Sheet1").Select
        
        .ActiveSheet.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rsClone
        
        For i = 1 To rsClone.Fields.Count
            xlApp.ActiveSheet.Cells(1, i).Value = rsClone.Fields(i - 1).Name
        Next i
        'xlApp.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit 'Autofit for column width
    End With
End Sub
```

I would like to suggest you to build a criteria then make a temporary query on the fly and export that query to excel and then delete the query. See below sub as an example. This is most efficient way to export filtered data to excel.

```
Private Sub cmdExportSubFormData_Click()
Dim strCriteria As String
Dim strSql As String
Dim qdf As QueryDef
    
    '============= Filter data between two date. =====================================================================
    If (Not IsNull(Me.txtStartDate)) Or (Not IsNull(Me.txtEndDate)) Then
         strCriteria = "[DoD]>= #" & Me.txtStartDate & "# " & "AND [DoD] <= #" & Me.txtEndDate & "# "
    Else
         strCriteria = ""
    End If


    '============== Condition-1 ======================================================================================
    If Not IsNull(Me.txtJobNo) Then
          If Len(strCriteria) > 0 Then
             strCriteria = strCriteria & "AND [JobNo] LIKE '*" & Me.txtJobNo & "*' "
          Else
             strCriteria = "[JobNo] LIKE '*" & Me.txtJobNo & "*' "
          End If
    Else
         strCriteria = strCriteria
    End If

    '============== Condition-2 ======================================================================================
    If Not IsNull(Me.cboFactory) Then
          If Len(strCriteria) > 0 Then
             strCriteria = strCriteria & "AND [Factory] LIKE '*" & Me.cboFactory & "*' "
          Else
             strCriteria = "[Factory] LIKE '*" & Me.cboFactory & "*' "
          End If
    Else
         strCriteria = strCriteria
    End If

    '============== Condition-3 ======================================================================================
    If Not IsNull(Me.cboBuyer) Then
          If Len(strCriteria) > 0 Then
             strCriteria = strCriteria & "AND [Buyer] LIKE '*" & Me.cboBuyer & "*' "
          Else
             strCriteria = "[Buyer] LIKE '*" & Me.cboBuyer & "*' "
          End If
    Else
         strCriteria = strCriteria
    End If

    '============== Condition-4 ======================================================================================
    If Not IsNull(Me.txtRef) Then
          If Len(strCriteria) > 0 Then
             strCriteria = strCriteria & "AND [Reference] LIKE '*" & Me.txtRef & "*' "
          Else
             strCriteria = "[Reference] LIKE '*" & Me.txtRef & "*' "
          End If
    Else
         strCriteria = strCriteria
    End If
    
    '============== Condition-4 ======================================================================================
    If Not IsNull(Me.cboSalesPerson) Then
          If Len(strCriteria) > 0 Then
             strCriteria = strCriteria & "AND [SalesPerson] LIKE '*" & Me.cboSalesPerson & "*' "
          Else
             strCriteria = "[SalesPerson] LIKE '*" & Me.cboSalesPerson & "*' "
          End If
    Else
         strCriteria = strCriteria
    End If
    
    '============== Condition-4 ======================================================================================
    If Not IsNull(Me.txtRcvDate) Then
          If Len(strCriteria) > 0 Then
             strCriteria = strCriteria & "AND [ReceivedDate] = #" & Me.txtRcvDate & "# "
          Else
             strCriteria = "[ReceivedDate] = #" & Me.txtRcvDate & "# "
          End If
    Else
         strCriteria = strCriteria
    End If
    
    '============== Condition-4 ======================================================================================
    If Not IsNull(Me.cboStatus) Then
          If Len(strCriteria) > 0 Then
             strCriteria = strCriteria & "AND [Status] = '" & Me.cboStatus & "' "
          Else
             strCriteria = "[Status] = '" & Me.cboStatus & "' "
          End If
    Else
         strCriteria = strCriteria
    End If
    
    '============== Condition-4 ======================================================================================
    If Not IsNull(Me.cboUnit) Then
          If Len(strCriteria) > 0 Then
             strCriteria = strCriteria & "AND [Unit] = '" & Me.cboUnit & "' "
          Else
             strCriteria = "[Unit] = '" & Me.cboUnit & "' "
          End If
    Else
         strCriteria = strCriteria
    End If



strSql = "SELECT * FROM tblMasterLocal WHERE " & strCriteria

On Error Resume Next
'Delete the query if it already exists
DoCmd.DeleteObject acQuery, "qryExportSubForm"

Set qdf = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("qryExportSubForm", strSql) 'as already in example
'DoCmd.OpenQuery qdf.Name 'Open query to see filtered data.

DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "qryExportSubForm", acFormatXLSX, "Challan_Status.xlsx", True

'release memory
'qdf.Close 'i changed qdef to qdf here and below
Set qdf = Nothing
DoCmd.DeleteObject acQuery, "qryExportSubForm"

End Sub
```